# How to set request args with Flask test_client?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, flask, flask-testing

I have to test out a certain view that gets certain information from `request.args`.

I can't mock this since a lot of stuff in the view uses the request object.
The only alternative I can think of is to manually set `request.args`.

I can do that with the `test_request_context()`, e.g:

```
with self.app.test_request_context() as req:
    req.request.args = {'code': 'mocked access token'}
    MyView()
```

Now the request inside this view will have the arguments that I've set.
However I need to call my view, not just initialize it, so I use this:

```
with self.app.test_client() as c:
    resp = c.get('/myview')
```

But I don't know how to manipulate the request arguments in this manner.

I have tried this:

```
with self.app.test_client() as c:
    with self.app.test_request_context() as req:
        req.request.args = {'code': 'mocked access token'}
        resp = c.get('/myview')
```

but this does not set `request.args`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Pass the `query_string` argument to `c.get`, which can either be a `dict`, a `MultiDict`, or an already encoded string.

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    r = c.get('/', query_string={'name': 'davidism'})
```

The [test client request methods](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/test/#werkzeug.test.Client.open) pass their arguments to Werkzeug's [`EnvironBuilder`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder), which is where this is documented.